# Do I need to use wp_reset_postdata for my function?

Tags: functions

I am using this function which seems to work fine, however I was wondering if I must use `wp_reset_postdata` after `endwhile`?

```
function evecal_task_function() {
$args=array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'events'
);
$now = time();
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  $fxdate = strtotime(get_field('fl_date',false,false));$datediff = $now - $fxdate;
    if ( $datediff > 1) {update_field('fl_expire', '1', get_the_ID());}  
  endwhile;
endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should, otherwise you could interfere with another query happening on the same page.

Using `$the_query->the_post();` interferes with the global `$post` variable, and `wp_reset_postdata()` serves that exact purpose, to reset the global `$post` variable to the original (global) query. [*Read more*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/)